# Pycharm: Delete to beginning of line

Tags: macos, pycharm, keymapping

I'm using Pycharm CE on OSX, and the Cmd+Backspace behaviour is really strange: It does some kind of combination of "delete to beginning of line" and "delete line", which seems to vary depending on the context.

How can I configure Pycharm to have the default Mac-like behaviour of Cmd+Backspace?

Answer (score 0):

It's not varying about context, it will vary with caret position. check it out
and the default cmd+BS deletes to word start

Answer (score 0):

There is "delete to line start" hotkey in Pycharm 4 (early access version) right now